# How to load GeoJSON with google-maps-react?

Tags: google-maps-react

I'm trying to load a GeoJSON layer onto my React Google Map. I know in plain JS you can use map.data.loadGeoJson(), but this doesn't seem to be supported in google-maps-react. Is there a way to make this work or at least a work around for this?

I tried this solution but it isn't working for me: https://medium.com/@dmw9400/using-geojson-with-google-maps-api-5127f7498a33

Getting the GeoJSON file in componentDidMount:

```
    const { feedInfo } = this.props;
    const geojson = await this.props.store.feeds.getGeojson(feedInfo.feed_code);
    const coordinates = geojson.geometry.coordinates;
    await this.setState({ coords: coordinates });
  }
```

Attempting to change GeoJSON into polygon format:

```
   const { coords } = this.state;
    let coordArr = [];
    coords.map(coord => coordArr.push({ lat: coord[1], lng: coord[0] }));
      return (
        <Polygon
          paths={coordArr}
          strokeColor={POLYGON_STYLE.BORDER_COLOR}
          strokeOpacity={0.8}
          strokeWeight={2}
          fillColor={POLYGON_STYLE.BACKGROUND_COLOR}
          fillOpacity={0.35}
        />);
  }
```

Rendering map:

```
    return (

      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        onReady={this.autoCenterMap}
      >
      {this.loadPolygon()}
      </Map>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using the map parameter in onReady, and then used map.data.addGeoJson instead of loadGeoJson.

```
     <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        onReady={this.autoCenterMap}
      />

autoCenterMap = ({ google }, map) => {
    this.loadGeoJson(map);
*code continues*
  }

loadGeoJson = async (map) => {
    const geojsonRoutes = await this.getRoutes(feed_code);
    const geojsonEnvelope = await this.getEnvelope(feed_code)
    map.data.addGeoJson(geojsonEnvelope);
    map.data.addGeoJson(geojsonRoutes); // # load geojson layer
}
```

Comment: can you show the example of envelope and routes?